# How to do custom changes on the image once loaded using Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to load image in my RV adapter. I use the following code for that:

```
Glide.with(activity).asBitmap().load(imageURL).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        // Set default
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
        return false;
    }
}).into(holder.imageAvatar);
```

It works great but I want to do some custom changes on the `Bitmap` before setting it into the `imageAvatar` ImageView. The changes I want to do:

```
final Bitmap circleAvatarBitmap = tileProvider.getCircularImage(avatarBitmap);
holder.avatarImage.setImageBitmap(circleAvatarBitmap); // Should be converted to '.into(holder.imageAvatar);'
```

How can I do custom changes on the image once loaded?

Comment: do you just want to circle the image?

Comment: Yes but with my own methods